# Написать функцию get()

Tags: php

Написать функцию get, для получения таких результатов
(есть подсказка, какой-то внутренний счетчик, а еще анонимная функция)

Спасибо заранее!!

```
$a = get(5); 

echo $a(3); // 8 
echo $a(2); // 10
```

Comment: Что значит "написать функцию get"? В чем вопрос?

Comment: @MikhailGrebenev видимо чувак прокачивает себе рейтинг )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно подобное сделать при помощи [анонимной функции](http://php.net/manual/ru/functions.anonymous.php)

Код представлен ниже:

```
function get($a)
{
    return function($b) use (&$a) {
        $a = $b + $a;
        return $a;
    };
}

$a = get(5);

echo $a(3)."\n";
echo $a(2)."\n";
```

**DEMO**: https://ideone.com/8or9aG